Clicking on the right mouse button during dragging fires the DragDrop Event instead of canceling the operation
For my VCL StringGrid component, I have successfully implemented the whole DragAndDrop operation for swapping the rows.
The unique problem that remains is that when I click on the right mouse button during dragging a row (means holding the left mouse button), the system still fires the DragDrop event and the operation is successfully finalized instead of being cancelled.
How can I avoid it?
There seems to be an empty DragCanceled method from TControl that can be overwritten. But it is unclear to me how I should implement it in my VCL StringGrid as there is no OnDragCanceled event.

When asking a code related question, the very first tag you should add is for the language you're using.

Why would you right-click to cancel a drag? Does pressing Esc not cancel it? What does your dragging code actually look like? In any case, DragCanceled() is just to notify the control being dragged that the drag was canceled. It's called before the control's OnEndDrag event. If the drag was canceled, the Target will be null.

Yes, ESC cancel it as well. But you can try in Windows to drag a file over a folder and right-click, the file is not moved into the folder. I am using the StartDrag, DragOver, DragDrop and DragEnd events.

I checked which events are fired when I right-click during dragging, DragDrop as well as DragEnd like I would drop the object, no difference in parameters, too. When I cancel with ESC, DragDrop is not fired and in EndDrag the parameter Target is blank like you said.

Regarding the DragCanceled() method, I reimplemented it but it is not called when I cancel the drag and drop operation, what I am missing? I mean I cannot assign it in the way I am doing for the other operations like: OnDragDrop = DragDrop (my Method) because there is no OnDragCanceled event I could assign.

@Mauro dragging items around in Windows Explorer is based on OLE interfaces (IDragSource, IDropTarget, IDataObject). Dragging items around inside a VCL UI uses a custom mechanism built into the VCL. Completely separate things. So it makes sense they would not have identical behaviors. The VCL implementors probably didn't think of supporting right clicking during dragging. You are going to have to dig into the VCL source code to figure out if what you want is even possible without modifying the source code.
